# Auto display django object detail

Tags: django, forms, model

I am looking for something like django Forms, not for getting informations, but for displaying them : Actually, I use Forms to ask the user some informations. When you use the django ModelForm's, it is very simple : the form is deduced from a model. Now, I would like a library that display the object details without having to specify labels and object attributes one-by-one into a template : basically, I would like a kind of "ViewForm" library, that does the same than ModelForm, but instead of displaying INPUT fields, will display just the chosen object attributes.

Does that exist ?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [databrowse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/)? It's not exactly  what you're looking for (it's more like the admin interface than a modular component like a `ModelForm`) and it's still pretty new, but you might learn from their approach.

Comment: In fact, I planned to do something like that : form=MyModelForm(instance=myobject), then in the template : I display the form.as_p with a filter that replace 'INPUT value=xxx' by just 'xxx'. But it is quite ugly...

Comment: Hello from 3 years later ! Do you have a feedback ? I ask myself the same questions. databrowse looks nice but needs a lot of tweaking to be usable. It would be awesome to have a similar feature in the admin, i.e. a page to browse the data and a link in each page/field to change it. But I suppose in a real life app we would need to modify a lot the templates, the admin actions, etc, so wouldn't it be quicker to write our own templates for browsing ?